# Postgres & PHP- Converting UTC timestamps to local time

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, date, timezone

I'm new to Postgres/SQL. All of the timestamps in the DB I'm working are stored as UTC format.

I'm trying to execute the following query but all of my results are off because of the timezone difference.  How do I fix this in this query? I'm working in America\Chicago or CST timezone.

```
select id FROM audit_log WHERE (action_id LIKE '%auth%' AND successful = 'true' AND timestamp BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to'

$from = date("Y-m-d 06:00:00");
$to = date("Y-m-d 11:59:59");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your UTC timestmp to timezone PST with the following expression:

```
timestamp at time zone 'utc' at time zone 'cst'
```

In your query:

```
select id 
FROM audit_log 
WHERE 
    action_id LIKE '%auth%' 
    AND successful = 'true' 
    AND timestamp at time zone 'utc' at time zone 'cst' BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

Unrelated notes:

- if `successful` is a boolean, you can just do `WHERE ... AND successful AND ...`
- you should use parameterized queries rather than concatenating variables in the query string; this makes your code more secure and more efficient.

Comment: To handle daylight saving time correctly, and to avoid ambiguities where an abbreviation can be interpreted in different ways, you should prefer the full IANA time zone identifier, `'America/Chicago'`.

Comment: Thanks, still not sure if this the right approach, only because this addition to the query takes so much longer to complete.  Sometimes it just times out. Is that expected?